# NiFi - connect to another instance (S2S)

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to use the SiteToSiteProvenance Reporting Task.

The objective is to send provenance data between two dockerized instances of NiFi, one at port 8080 and another at port 9090.

I've created a input port creatively called "IN" on the destination NiFi and the service configuration on the source NiFi is:

[image]

However I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to refresh Remote Group's peers due to Unable to communicate with remote NiFi cluster in order to determine which nodes exist in the remote cluster

I've also exposed the port 10000 in the destination docker.

Comment: Seems like there is a networking issue between your two docker containers, are you sure container 1 can reach container 2 using whatever host and port you put in the Destination URL property?

Comment: It was our theory too. We end up dropping containers altogethers and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it appears there was a networking issue between the containers.

It was finally resolved by the asker by not using containers.